# Is there a way on PHPSpreadSheet to draw chart using currency data?

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Im loading an excel file containing money data, to be able to draw it as a chart using PhpSpreadSheet:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 5,1$ | 7,3$ |
| 6,2$ | 8,4$ |

I am importing my data like this :

```
$toLoad = 'test.xlsx';
$loaded = IOFactory::load($toLoad);

$worksheet = $loaded->getSheetByName('test');

$writer = new Xlsx($loaded);

//Here comes the problem : 
$dataSeriesValues1 = [
    new DataSeriesValues(StyleNumberFormat::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'test!$A$1:$A$2', null, 2),
];
```

the `'test!$A$1:$A$2'` works fine when i take the dollar sign from the excel.

Thank you

Tried various data series values format like : `StyleNumberFormat::FORMAT_ACCOUNTING_EUR`

Answer (score 0):

Start by recognising that `5,1$` is a string value in the cell, and not a number, and the chart dataseries requires an actual numeric value.

You need to set the cell values as floats, not as formatted strings.

If you want to retain the appearance of the cell value as a currency when it's a number, then you can use a number format mask to set its style.